# how to train a network using single layer perceptron for ocr?

Tags: c#, ocr, neural-network, perceptron

I'm developing a program to recognize a character from a image using OCR techniques. Up till now I have used a method that scanned the image, but now I have to use neural networks. Please explain what is a single layer perceptron and how to use it to train the network.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your post for grammar and spelling. Please check to make sure it still makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I typed a portion of your question into [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=single+layer+perceptron+how+to+use+it+to+train+the+network.&meta=):  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network

You might also use this CodeProject article, [Creating Optical Character Recognition (OCR) applications using Neural Networks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simple_ocr.aspx?display=Print), as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a basic explanation on Perceptron / Artificial Neural Network may help you. I wrote an article "An Intuitive Example of Artificial Neural Network (Perceptron) Detecting Cars / Pedestrians from a Self-driven Car"

https://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10

You can check. Hopefully, you will find it useful.

[[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhReW.jpg)](https://www.spicelogic.com/Journal/Perceptron-Artificial-Neural-Networks-10)